# The non-oriented curvilinear integral verification

Tags: integration, analysis

Calculate the non-oriented curvilinear integral

$\int_\gamma(2xy+y^2)dl$

$\gamma$ - broken line connecting points $(1,0),(1,0),(5,0)$

Parameterization:

$(0,1),(1,0)$

$\begin{cases}
  x(t)=t \\
  y(t)=-t+1
\end{cases}$

$\begin{cases}
  x'(t)=1 \\
  y'(t)=-1
\end{cases}$

$(0,1),(5,0)$

$\begin{cases}
  x(t)=5t \\
  y(t)=-t+1
\end{cases}$

$\begin{cases}
  x'(t)=5 \\
  y'(t)=-1
\end{cases}$

$(1,0),(5,0)$

$\begin{cases}
  x(t)=4t+1 \\
  y(t)=0
\end{cases}$

$\begin{cases}
  x'(t)=4 \\
  y'(t)=0
\end{cases}$

Integral:

$\int_0^1(2t(-t+1)+(-t+1)^2 \sqrt{1^2+(-1)^2}dt$ + $\int_0^1(2*5t(-t+1)+(-t+1) \sqrt{5^2+(-1)^2}dt$ + $\int_0^1(2(4t+1)*0+0 \sqrt{4^2+0^2}dt=...=\frac{4\sqrt2 + 10\sqrt26}{6}$

I care more about the method than the result, 
but it would be good ofc if the result is correct.